# Implementing bare-metal RISC-V on the Nexys-A7-100T FPGA

Tags: fpga, riscv, bare-metal

I've recently taken up a project where I must implement a bare-metal RISC-V processor on the Nexys A7 100T FPGA board and run a simple hello world code on it.

However, I'm a bit new to RISC-V and have been struggling to get started with the bare-metal implementation. I've managed to implement RISC-V running on Debian Linux onto the board using the Github repository from Eugene Tarassov who is a principal engineer at Xilinx but this obviously did not meet the project specification since it's not bare-metal.

FPGA RISC-V SoC running Debian Linux: https://github.com/eugene-tarassov/vivado-risc-v#readme

I would greatly appreciate any books, online resources, tutorials or guidance that would help with this project. Thanks

Comment: you are overcomplicating this, you need the risc-v docs from that organization and from the hardware folks managing the fpga will tell you how to put your handful of instructions where the core can boot into them.  likewise the address map to show where the uart is, what those registers are and clock enables, etc.  no different than using an mcu except this one is probably simpler.   the bootloader for the full blown linux and how that gets programmed into the system is also info to help you out, can probably use the same tool to load your tiny program.

Comment: an intermediate path depending on the bootloader used for your linux solution, is to have it not launch linux and instead launch your bare metal program.  that will get through a number of the basics.  then you can replace that bootloader.

Comment: if you have never done any of this before then probably start in a qemu sim, generally the simulated uarts you can just write to and not actually iniatilize, so literally a few lines of asm.   and easy to launch.  if no risc-v then do it with an arm one...not sure what part of this you are asking as there is the tools side of it, the accessing peripherals, etc.   99.999 and a lot of nines percent of baremetal is reading, you only need the riscv docs and the ardware docs, being an fpga means it is dynamic, who is doing the fpga and can you talk to them or do they have docs?

Answer (score 1):

For your hands-on check following github resources:

- [Rudi-RV32I](https://github.com/hamsternz/Rudi-RV32I/tree/master/c)
- [Picorv32](https://github.com/YosysHQ/picorv32)
- [RISC-V microcontroller-like SoC (VHDL)](https://github.com/stnolting/neorv32)
- [Nexys A7 port](https://github.com/stnolting/neorv32/tree/master/setups/vivado)
- ["Hello world" example program](https://github.com/stnolting/neorv32/tree/master/sw/example/hello_world)
- [RISCV-Formal](https://github.com/SymbioticEDA/riscv-formal)

Since you have asked for online resources check some of the following links:

- [RISCV Specifications](https://riscv.org/technical/specifications/)
- [RISCV Technical Forums](https://riscv.org/technical/technical-forums/)
- [RISCV Tech wiki](https://wiki.riscv.org/display/TECH)
- [RISCV University Resources](https://riscv.org/learn/university-resources/)
- [From Custom CPU to Hello World in 30 Minutes](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/From-Custom-CPU-to-Hello-World-in-30-Minutes_v1.pdf)
- [RISCV Publications](https://riscv.org/publications/)

Book(s)

- [The RISC-V Reader: An Open Architecture Atlas](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/David-Patterson/dp/0999249118)
- [RISC-V Assembly Language](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Anthony-J-Dos-Reis/dp/1088462006)

A general RISCV archive git page:

- [RISCV Archive](https://github.com/riscvarchive)